# Is there a real problem with using i.e. get method instead of put in an action through clicking on a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, httprequest

For example I have button for thumbs up or I want to resend a specific mail or I change a specific enum state through clicking on a button (like published/unpublished)

Now regarding the rails implementation, I can make it work using either `put`, `get` or `patch`, since I only have to send a specific id.

In my opinion it seems to be best practice using `patch`, `post` or `put` wheter one or several attributes will change on my objects. So this seems mainly to be a convention here.

On the server side I will have to add some policies to allow only specific users to do so, but beyond adding policies are there any possible issues with not using the conventional http-method here?

Comment: There are no actual *issues* that I am aware of. Honestly `PUT/PATCH` and `DELETE` are really just `POST` requests in disguise because modern browsers only make `GET` and `POST` requests. That being said the HTTP verbs convey meaning and intention (by specification), i.e. REST more or less dictates GET is for data reads not modification, POST is generally for data/resource creation (however it can be used for data retrieval where the query is too long for a GET request), `PUT/PATCH` are for updating/modifying data for an existing resource, and `DELETE` well...

Comment: ok I think so as well, was just interested if there is anything that I am not considering. It makes sense regarding readability of code to know what is intended to do.

Comment: What you are discussing is convention for the sake of understanding and adherence to the specification. Nothing prevents me from making a DELETE request and returning 201 (Created) or making a GET request that is successful but returning 404 (Resource Not Found)  however these results would be very confusing to another programmer because the resulting status does not match the outcome. Imagine you asked me: *"Can you help me with this question?"* and I said: *"Certainly"* and then proceeded to ignore you or worse yet deleted your post entirely. You would likely be very confused .

Comment: GET requests should not alter or create resources since they are stored in the browsers history. Your users (and boss) won't be happy if  hitting the back button creates, deletes or updates a resource.  Just as long as you separate the idempotent (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) and non-idempotent (PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE) methods it is really just a matter of semantics as pointed out by @engineersmnky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very real problem with using GET is that is supposed to be an idempotent method. Lets say *the new guy* creates the form:

```
get '/things/create', to: "things#create"
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: '/posts/create', method: :get) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title])
    @post.save
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
end
```

He then tries it out in the browser in and is perfectly happy with it. Mission accomplished.

His boss then attempts to test it. He creates a Post titled "This new guy might not be so bad anyways". And then he hits the back button to try creating another Post. Weirdly it just loops back to the index page. He tries it again - the only thing that happens is that the page starts to fill up with "This new guy might not be so bad anyways" and he is becomes less and less convinced that its actually true.

If you used POST, PATCH, PUT or DELETE the browser would have warned him that he is about to resend a form. Thats why GET should never change anything on the server (besides maybe your pageview stats).

It also opens up for any malicous actor to get users to create, delete or modify resources simply by fooling them into clicking a link. The malicous actor doesn't even have to got though the effort of creating a phishing site and circumventing the anti-CSRF protection that Rails provides.

There is absolutely no difference between how POST, PATCH, PUT or DELETE are treated by the client or server beyond the conventions of Rails.

But since Rails is a highly convention driven framework which adheres to a specific flavor of REST it really befits you to follow those conventions if you want to be productive and not be *that new guy*.

When it comes to actions beyond the classical CRUD verbs its really down to your best judgement and intent is really what matters. What does the action do? Is it updating something (PATCH)? Is it actually a separate resource? (`POST /mails/1/mailouts`). As you may see there is no easy answer. Just be clear and document what you're doing if you're unsure.

Comment: I am a little bit confused with going back and the example. so every time open /things/create it would try to create the post even though I haven't filled anything in. For going back it uses the cashed data and probably creates again. But why should the form refill? And for opening for the first time it would probably say please fill in values with proper validations.

would it be able to add params to the link that link, when somebody tries to fool on this.

Comment: I this case it won't actually "refill" the form. Pressing the back button will send `/things/create?title=...` and create a new record and redirect the user back to the index page. Redirects are not normally cached. Its a contrived example but it illustrates why using GET can lead to very unexpected behavior.